# Java timezone issue with Joda Time

Tags: java, date, tomcat, timezone, jodatime

I have a rather vexing issue with some date parsing and getting the right date/time from my formatting. Here's the code (condensed version) thats doing the formatting

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
log.debug("Trying to convert {} using format {}.", val, "yyyy-MM-dd");
Date toDate = formatter.parseDateTime(inputText).toDate();
log.debug("Converted value to {}", toDate);
```

Here's some output with the **incorrect** values. The timezone here is set to EDT. (checked via the `date` command and by the /etc/localtime symlink.

```
13:14:53.618 [http-bio-8080-exec-13] DEBUG c.s.e.p.j.AbstractParamToObjectProvider - Trying to convert 2013-07-08 using format yyyy-MM-dd.
13:14:53.619 [http-bio-8080-exec-13] DEBUG c.s.e.p.j.AbstractParamToObjectProvider - Converted value to Sun Jul 07 20:00:00 EDT 2013
```

This is running on AWS-LINUX on Tomcat 7 using OpenJDK 7. We have another instance running on AWS, and the same code produces this:

```
17:22:46.164 [http-bio-8080-exec-239] DEBUG c.s.e.p.j.AbstractParamToObjectProvider - Trying to convert 2013-07-08 using format yyyy-MM-dd.
17:22:46.165 [http-bio-8080-exec-239] DEBUG c.s.e.p.j.AbstractParamToObjectProvider - Converted value to Mon Jul 08 00:00:00 UTC 2013
```

The timezone on this machine is set to UTC.

On my local machine, the output is also correct (back to EDT here running oracles JDK on OS X):

```
13:24:55.967 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-176] DEBUG c.s.e.p.j.AbstractParamToObjectProvider - Trying to convert 2013-07-08 using format yyyy-MM-dd.
13:24:56.089 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-176] DEBUG c.s.e.p.j.AbstractParamToObjectProvider - Converted value to Mon Jul 08 00:00:00 EDT 2013
```

Again, same code in all three spots. I can not for the life of me figure out why we have an instance that does not act like the rest of them. I'm going to add some more debugging output to try and narrow it down, but as of right now I'm out of luck.

Also, another interesting bit. Running outside of Tomcat on the machine that is wrong, with the same jdk and the following code I get what I expect:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime parseDateTime = f.parseDateTime("2013-07-08");
System.out.println(parseDateTime.toDate());
```

Output:

```
Mon Jul 08 00:00:00 EDT 2013
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like Joda is not using the System default timezone. Here's how I'm outputting the data:

```
log.debug("Using joda timezone of: {}", DateTimeZone.getDefault());
log.debug("Default timezone of: {}", TimeZone.getDefault());
```

And here's the output:

```
AbstractParamToObjectProvider - Using joda timezone of: UTC
AbstractParamToObjectProvider - Default timezone of: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]
```

One of these things does not match the other...any ideas why?

**SOLUTION**

Jon was in the right direction with his answer, but here's the final run down.

Somehow user.timezone was set to UTC and Joda was using that, while the default TimeZone was not (that was using the system timezone). For a patch I did the following:

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()));
```

Just to make sure things match. A 'proper' fix is to set the system default timezone explicitly on app startup.

Comment: Try printing the time zone of the parsed `DateTime`: `DateTime parsed = formatter.parseDateTime(inputText); System.out.println(parsed.getZone());` Also, if you're parsing a date, why are you parsing it to `DateTime` instead of `LocalDate` anyway?

Comment: Also, try printing out `DateTimeZone.getDefault` on each machine - I wonder whether it's not picking that up appropriately, so it's using a different default to the one that the JDK has.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thats what I'm wondering, and why is it only doing it in tomcat. Just deployed some changes with more debug info (with tz spit out), so will see what that says.

Comment: @JonSkeet See my update, it appears Joda is not picking the same timezone that the Java classes are.

Comment: What's the value of your `user.timezone` system property? And is anything else setting that?

Comment: Small tips… (a) Rather than specify that pattern, use Joda-Time’s built-in formatter: `DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.date();`. (b) No need for a formatter in your case, as the Date-Time class can parse that ISO 8601 formatted string directly in its constructor: `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2013-07-08", DateTimeZone.UTC );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joda Time goes through the following steps:

- Use the `user.timezone` system property
- Create a time zone based on the ID of `TimeZone.getDefault()`
- Fall back to UTC

`TimeZone.getDefault()` can be a little bit more complicated, although it also uses `user.timezone` in many cases.

One option would be to *explicitly* set the default time zone for both `TimeZone` and `DateTimeZone` to UTC on application start-up: for web servers, it's the most reasonable default to use (although personally I prefer to explicitly state the time zone where appropriate).

Comment: It appears that the user.timezone property is causing the issue. However, I have no idea where this is being set from as for Tomcat (can't find any place where it should be referenced and actually being set).

Comment: I concur with Jon Skeets's advice to specify the desired time zone in your code rather than depend on any default. Joda-Time provides a constant for UTC: `DateTimeZone.UTC`. For example, `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2013-07-08", DateTimeZone.UTC );’